# Inform7: Working with properties of rooms

Tags: runtime-error, inform7

I'm very, very new to this language, and wrapping my head around "how to do things with stuff" is proving to be a very frustrating endeavor.

My goal here is to create a mechanic where certain rooms are dangerous, and become more dangerous the longer the player stays in them. If the player stays in a dangerous room for too long, a death scene is triggered.

I've got code that looks like this:

```
[The "danger rule"]
A room has a number called danger level. The danger level of a room is usually 0.

Definition: A room is dangerous if its danger level is 1 or more.
Definition: A room is deadly if its danger level is 9 or more.

Every turn (this is the increasing danger rule):
    If the player is in a dangerous room:
        Increase danger level by 1.

Every turn (this is the death by danger rule):
    If the room is deadly:
        do nothing.[Later...]

Every turn (this is the danger explanation rule):
    say danger level.

[further down]

The Feeding Chamber is south of the dungeon."You enter a large, dimly lit room with straw on the floor, surrounded by various cages embedded in the wall.[line break]Blood spatters are all over the floor, and it looks as if there's been a fight recently". After going to the feeding chamber for the first time:
    try looking;
    say "It smells like grues around here. I would be careful if I were you..";

The Feeding Chamber has danger level 5.
```

I can't seem to figure out how to properly work with the "danger level of a room". The explanation rule I defined causes a runtime error when entering a dangerous room:

```
`*** Run-time problem P31: Attempt to use a property of the 'nothing' non-object: property danger level`
```

..And attempts to re-word the rule to something like `the danger level of the room` or `the danger level of this room` lead to perplexing compilation messages such as:

```
`In the sentence 'say the danger level of the room'  , it looks as if you intend 'danger level of the room' to be a property, but 'a room' is not specific enough about who or what the owner is.`
```

What is the "right" way to reference properties of objects in this way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The magic words here were "`of the location`". If we pretend that that this was another programming language for a moment, the way I was writing this was as if I was referring to a class "`the room`" rather than an instance of the class currently being referenced "`the location`".

The working rule is as follows:

```
Every turn while the player is in a dangerous room:
        Increase danger level of the location by 1.
```

The trick is to give Inform enough information to know which particular thing you're referring to. The problematic sentence in the original question is perfectly valid english that a human could parse, but the computer needs a bit more help in determining what room we mean when we say "the room".